# OpenCV in Qt on Mac, How to Package?

Tags: macos, qt, opencv

The OpenCV that I use, is installed via brew:

```
brew install opencv
```

and this is my .pro file configuration:

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  /usr/local/include/opencv4 \
                    /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2
LIBS += /usr/local/lib/libopencv_*
```

I use the `macdeployqt` command:

```
macdeployqt testopencv.app
```

At this point, the app cannot be opened on other Mac OS.

So, I use the `otool -L` command to see the path:

```
otool -L testopencv.app/Contents/MacOS/testopencv
```

I moved all the OpenCV libraries that I use, to the inside of the app,
and changed all OpenCV paths to app internal paths.

Just like this.

```
cp /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.4.5.dylib /Users/plf/qt/testopencv/testopencv.app/Contents/Frameworks/
install_name_tool -change /usr/local/opt/opencv/lib/libopencv_core.4.5.dylib @executable_path/../Frameworks/libopencv_core.4.5.dylib testopencv.app/Contents/MacOS/testopencv
```

until all OpenCV paths become

@executable_path/... /Frameworks/xxxxxxxxx

But now I moved the packaged app to other Mac OS but it still doesn't work.

What should I have to do? Is there any extra step?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, the reason is that the opencv library reference from brew install is too messy, I directly use cmake to recompile a copy of the opencv dylib file by myself, perfect solution.